# SQL Server Persisted columns with value evaluated from function

Tags: sql-server-2008, view

Is it possible in Sql Server (2008, R2) to have a persisted column with a value resulting from a scalar function which queries other tables?
I'm running into performance problems since I have a field that should be evaluated considering values coming from other tables.
I logically solved the problem creating (indexed) views and evaluating the field using CASE WHEN, but now I'm running into performance issues with lot of data.

My idea is to evaluate the CASE WHEN in a function and use it as persisted column in the main table.
Is it possible? Will changes in the views trigger an update of the value?

Can you suggest me alternative solutions (other than triggers)?

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible. Persisted computed columns need to be deterministic and can't rely on data from other tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is possible, it's almost certainly a bad idea.

Triggers are there for a reason, and this is an ideal example. Why do you not want to use them?

Comment: In the past, I experienced performance issues during updates. But probably it's just moving the problem around, so I will try with triggers.
Thanks